# c# sending messages to local syslog service on linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, syslog

Is there a way to send log messages to the local syslog service on centos 7 within a c# program? In python there is the [syslog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html) library but with c# the only way sems o be a UDP message ouver the network.

Answer (score 1):

There are several c# libraries for syslog, I used this one on a recent project

https://github.com/emertechie/SyslogNet

Answer (score 1):

[Dislaimer: I wrote this]

Heres my "gist" with a (very) lightweight Syslog library for .NET Core that uses p/invoke into `libc`

https://github.com/jitbit/SyslogCore

It's only 66 lines of code, feel free to simply throw it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serilog for logging and add a syslog sink e.g.: https://github.com/vermeeca/Serilog.Sinks.Syslog or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.SyslogMessages/